# Entity Framework - Duplicate related entities when calling SaveChanges inside of insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I am creating a new Parent entity with a new Child entity on the client side. This is a one to many relationship.

```
//Client has created a new Parent with a new Child attached 
//e.g. Parent.Child = new Child();
//This is submitted to the server, and ends up here:
public void InsertParent(Parent parent)
{ 
    ObjectContext.Parents.AddObject(parent); //No Parent.ID yet
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges(); //Now I have a Parent.ID

    //Do some stuff with the Parent.ID here. (Nothing is changed with the Parent or Child, just using Parent.ID)
}
```

My problem is that after all of this, I end up with *two* child entities in the database. My guess is that EF already has an insert for the child queued and when I call SaveChanges, it creates another insert for the same child entity.

The reason I have SaveChanges here is I wish to do some stuff with the Parent.ID after the parent is created, but I need to persist the Parent before it will get an ID (primary key is created by the DB). When I take all of my extra code out (from SaveChanges on) everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is very old but I'm running into the same problem and haven't found a great way around it.  I'm using WPF with Binding.  I'm trying to insert one history record that's tied to a number of child tables.  What I ended up doing to make sure the children are not also inserted is:

```
Parent.ChildID = Parent.Child.ChildID;
Parent.Child = null;
```

This seems like a total hack but it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Put a breakpoint in this method to confirm that there's only one Child on the Parent.
- Return immediately after the SaveChanges() to confirm that none of your other 'stuff' is making any other changes
- Ensure that the ObjectContext is instantiated and disposed of properly. Why isn't this method instantiating the context - where is it coming from?

It's very hard to say what's happening here unless you do so more debugging and determine exactly where your problem is occurring.

Your operation should accept a Parent with Child, simply instantiate the context and insert. If you can confirm that it's just doing this then you'll more than likely find your problem.